# libDAI compile error

Tags: c++, linux, matlab, compiler-errors

I am hitting a compile error when trying to install libDAI (A free/open source C++ library for Discrete Approximate Inference methods)  on my ubuntu 14.04LTS system. I cloned the repo from [github](https://github.com/dbtsai/libDAI) , edited the makefile for my system (only change was my matlab directory) and run make, which hits this error -

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_program_options-mt

this is after doing all the related installs

> apt-get install g++ make doxygen graphviz libboost-dev
>   libboost-graph-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-test-dev
>   libgmp-dev cimg-dev

as well as a shot in the dark

> sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev

and another,  something that apparently worked for someone else namely

> sudo apt-get libboost-program-options-dev

which gives an error for me (E: Invalid operation libboost-program-options-dev)

i can't progress without this lib it seems, so i'm at a wall

on a hunch based on

> /sbin/ldconfig -p | grep libboost_program

I decided to take out the -mt part in the makefile , leaving me with

> BOOSTLIBS_PO=-lboost_program_options (instead of ...options-mt)

Now I get

> make /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/bin/mex -Iinclude CXX#g++
>   CXXFLAGS#'-Wno-deprecated -Wall -W -Wextra -fpic' -largeArrayDims 
>   -DDAI_WITH_BP -DDAI_WITH_FBP -DDAI_WITH_TRWBP -DDAI_WITH_MF -DDAI_WITH_HAK -DDAI_WITH_LC -DDAI_WITH_TREEEP -DDAI_WITH_JTREE -DDAI_WITH_MR -DDAI_WITH_GIBBS -DDAI_WITH_CBP -DDAI_WITH_DECMAP -lgmpxx -lgmp  -output matlab/dai.mexa64 src/matlab/dai.cpp src/matlab/matlab.cpp src/graph.cpp src/dag.cpp src/bipgraph.cpp
>   src/varset.cpp src/daialg.cpp src/alldai.cpp src/clustergraph.cpp
>   src/factor.cpp src/factorgraph.cpp src/properties.cpp
>   src/regiongraph.cpp src/util.cpp src/weightedgraph.cpp
>   src/exceptions.cpp src/exactinf.cpp src/evidence.cpp src/emalg.cpp
>   src/io.cpp src/bp.cpp src/fbp.cpp src/trwbp.cpp src/mf.cpp src/hak.cpp
>   src/lc.cpp src/treeep.cpp src/jtree.cpp src/mr.cpp src/gibbs.cpp
>   src/bbp.cpp src/cbp.cpp src/bp_dual.cpp src/decmap.cpp
>   /home/jeremy/jeremy.rutman@gmail.com/techdev/Research/clothes
>   specific/fashionista/fashionista_v0.2/lib/libdai/libdaigit/libDAI/CXX#g++
>   not found; check that you are in the correct current folder, and check
>   the spelling of
>   '/home/jeremy/jeremy.rutman@gmail.com/techdev/Research/clothes
>   specific/fashionista/fashionista_v0.2/lib/libdai/libdaigit/libDAI/CXX#g++'.

the makefile has the following

```
# MATLAB
# MatLab version 7.3 (R2006b) or newer?
NEW_MATLAB=true
# Replace the following by the directory where MatLab has been installed
MATLABDIR=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a
#echo $MATLABDIR
# The following should resolve to the MatLab mex compile command
MEX=$(MATLABDIR)/bin/mex
# Specify the C++ compiler and flags for MEX
#MEXFLAGS:='g++' 
MEXFLAGS:=CXX\#$(CC) CXXFLAGS\#'$(CCFLAGS)'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MEXFLAGS:=CXX=$(CC) CXXFLAGS='$(CCFLAGS)'
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!searchin/libdai/CXX$23g$2B$2B$20not$20found$3B$20check$20that$20you$20are$20in$20the$20correct$20current$20folder$2C$20and$20check$20the$20spelling$20of$20/libdai/zSofuAzk9Vo/zy3cW3jTozQJ

Comment: this was long-ago enough that I either dropped the ball, avoided the issue somehow , or solved it, and now can't recall...I think I found some variant version of libDAI that was ok, but am giving an upvote on the assumption that your solution works

Comment: Thanks. It did compile, I was also facing the same problem, and found the solution in  googlegroup. I have issues with compiling with MatLAB though

Answer (score 0):

I think the `_mt` suffix (for multithreading) is a thing of the past for boost. You will have to look into your package repository (`apt-cache search <name>`, try `boost` as `<name>`) to find out whether there still are package names that contain `mt` or `multithreading`. If not, you will have to change DAI's source code to look for the right libraries.

Comment: yeah I tried taking out the -mt inthe meantime on a hunch

Comment: yes, i now progressed to the error added to the original post : the  makefile is tacking the local directory onto the compiler name , more details put into post above

Comment: indeed.  any clues as to how i would go about fixing whatever it is thats wrong?